# How to use the HttpClient class CORRECTLY with proxy and cookie changing PER request (with multi-threading)

Tags: c#, multithreading

The HttpClient is supposed to be used as a singleton (even though its implementing IDisposable) due to the underlying sockets not being closed (leading to socket exhaustion). However, if you use it as intended (as a singleton), there is an issue with DNS changing.

There are other suggestions of using DI and the HttpClientFactory class, but none of these allow you to specify the proxy and cookies **per request**.

The idea:
I would like to be able to use the **.SendAsync()** method if it let me input a **WebProxy** and **CookieContainer** for the request to use.

NOTE: I could convert CookieContainer into a "Cookies" header value and set it on the HttpRequestMessage, but is there not an easier way to do it, directly from a CookieContainer, instead of having to create the parsing myself?

***QUESTION:***
Therefore, what would be the correct way to use the HttpClient class so that you can change proxy & cookies per HTTP request, with multi-threading support?

Comment: Are you using .NET Core?

Comment: I'm using the normal .NET Framework, such as .NET Framework 4.8